How to track redirects from another site to mine which is built-in as iframe inside the other site
We have site with domain siteB.com.  Inside we inserted our site that opens like an iframe with siteB.siteA.com. I have access only to siteA code and therefore the GTM and GA are implemented only on siteB.siteA.com.
I wonder if it's possible to track the redirects from siteB and to identify this traffic as referral. Because most of source/medium now is (direct)/(none).
Thank you!
I'm thinking about cross domain feature GA offers, but not sure if it works without the tracking code on siteB.com

Possible solutions
If I understand you, you have embedded (without embed code it's not possible to track) a form on your website provided by another domain such as paperform.co (it is an iFrame provider). If this is the case, then there are 2 solutions.

The iframe provider should have the option to insert GTM code.


) If they have the option then you can track the form by a postMassage Listener code through GTM


If the iframe provider doesn't have the option to insert GTM

<) Then you have to create a listener code from the console of siteB.com to track the form (it is a little difficult and takes a little time).
whatever your situation is, it can be tracked and it's not a corss-domain issue
Regards
facebook.com/motiurak07
